# Github beginner question related to cloning

Tags: git, github, repository, github-desktop

If I used Github Desktop to clone someone's repository and the original repo gets pushed a new commit, will the files on my cloned repo also automatically be updated accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to pull the latest commit from the remote repo to sync your local files with the latest changes. You can do this in GitHub Desktop or on the command line (`git pull`).

Answer (score 0):

No. Once you clone the repo, it is pulled from repo and rests in your local. It will not have any further updates made into the remote until you "pull" the changes.
You can use github desktop and choose the "Pull" option or use `git pull` as CLI